# How to pin an image onto another image css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I have this code:

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div style="position: relative; left:0; top:0;">

        <img src="images/fullscreen.png" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height:auto; position: relative; top:0; left:0;"/>
        <img src="images/smaller_animated.gif" style="position:absolute; top:140px; left:458px;"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

fullscreen.png is a large full screen image. I made it so its kind of responsive, so if you make the browser width less it doesn't scroll and instead resizes.

Now i have an animated gif that i want to place within an area of the fullscreen image. Basically there is a large rectangle grey background within that fullscreen image and i want to pin the animated gif to the centre of that space. That works fine except for when i resize the window, then the gif doesnt move/resize with the fullscreen image and moves outside the rectangle background.

Ive played around with making it absolute and relative but i dont seem to be getting close, any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use background image instead?

Comment: which size have your gif image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="fullscreen" align="center">
 <img class="center_image" src="images/smaller_animated.gif"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fullscreen {
    background: url(images/fullscreen.png) red;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    max-width: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.center_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - /* halve your height of image */);
    height: /* height of your image */;
    width: /* width of your image */;
}
```